# Crash and Centos

Tags: linux, centos

I've a big problem it's the second time that my server crashed. I tried to check every thing and seems correct except this /var/log/messages:

```
May 25 20:16:11 srv1 kernel: swap_free: Bad swap offset entry 00300000
May 25 20:16:33 srv1 kernel: swap_free: Unused swap offset entry 00080000
May 25 20:16:33 srv1 kernel: swap_free: Bad swap offset entry 00340000
May 25 20:16:33 srv1 kernel: swap_free: Unused swap offset entry 000c0000
May 25 20:16:33 srv1 kernel: swap_free: Bad swap offset entry 00a00000
May 25 20:16:33 srv1 kernel: swap_free: Bad swap offset entry 00200000
May 25 20:16:33 srv1 kernel: swap_free: Bad swap offset entry 00890000
May 25 20:16:33 srv1 kernel: swap_free: Unused swap offset entry 00080000
May 25 20:16:33 srv1 kernel: swap_free: Bad swap offset entry 00f00000
May 25 20:16:33 srv1 kernel: swap_free: Bad swap offset entry 00f90000
May 25 20:16:33 srv1 kernel: swap_free: Bad swap offset entry 00980000
May 25 20:16:33 srv1 kernel: swap_free: Bad swap offset entry 00980000
May 25 20:16:33 srv1 kernel: swap_free: Bad swap offset entry 00820000
May 25 20:16:33 srv1 kernel: swap_free: Unused swap offset entry 000d0000
May 25 20:16:33 srv1 kernel: swap_free: Bad swap offset entry 00a60000
May 25 20:16:33 srv1 kernel: swap_free: Bad swap offset entry 00a20000
May 25 20:16:33 srv1 kernel: swap_free: Bad swap offset entry 009a0000
May 25 20:16:33 srv1 kernel: swap_free: Bad swap offset entry 00170000
May 25 20:16:33 srv1 kernel: swap_free: Bad swap offset entry 00f20000
May 25 20:16:33 srv1 kernel: swap_free: Bad swap offset entry 00b60000
May 25 20:16:33 srv1 kernel: swap_free: Bad swap offset entry 00a30000
May 25 20:16:33 srv1 kernel: swap_free: Bad swap offset entry 00320000
May 25 20:16:47 srv1 kernel: swap_free: Bad swap offset entry 002c0000
May 25 20:16:47 srv1 kernel: Eeek! page_mapcount(page) went negative! (-1)
```

What can be my problem?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run a RAM test, your memory is likely bad.  A couple utilities:

- [Memtest86](http://www.memtest86.com/)
- [memtester](http://pyropus.ca/software/memtester/)

Comment: Argh, beat me to it by 10 seconds or so! I guess I'll be hitting that up arrow now instead :)

Comment: Thanks, could you help me using memtester (which is free and included in yum packages) ?

Comment: Im running now <pre>memtester 100</pre>, btw the problem can be that on my server I upgraded ram from 12 gb to 24gb ?

Comment: Yes.  One of the modules you added is most likely bad.

Comment: Great to hear this I ordered a ram replacement. Thanks so much!